# Ruby String/Array Write program

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

For a project that I am working on for school, one of the parts of the project asks us to take a collection of all the Federalist papers and run it through a program that essentially splits up the text and writes new files (per different Federalist paper).

The logic I decided to go with is to run a search, and every time the search is positive for "Federalist No." it would save into a new file everything until the next "Federalist No".
This is the algorithm that I have so far:

```
file_name = "Federalist" 
section_number = "1"

new_text = File.open(file_name + section_number, 'w')
i = 0 
n= 1
while i < l.length 
  if (l[i]!= "federalist") and (l[i+1]!= "No")
    new_text.puts l[i]
    i = i + i
  else 
    new_text.close
    section_number = (section_number.to_i +1).to_s
    new_text = File.open(file_name + section_number, "w")
    new_text.puts(l[i])
    new_text.puts(l[i+1])
    i=i+2
  end
end
```

After debugging the code as much as I could (I am a beginner at Ruby), the problem that I run into now is that because the `while` function always holds true, it never proceeds to the `else` command.

In terms of going about this in a different way, my TA suggested the following:

1. Put the entire text in one string by looping through the array(l) and adding each line to the one big string each time.
2. Split the string using the `split` method and the key word "FEDERALIST No." This will create an array with each element being one section of the text:

   ```
   arrayName = bigString.split("FEDERALIST No.")
   ```
3. You can then loop through this new array to create files for each element using a similar method you use in your program.

But as simple as it may sound, I'm having an extremely difficult time putting even that code together.

Comment: Is `l` the input? How is it initialized?

Comment: The input is an array of the Federalist papers listed before the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

`i = i + i`

`i` starts at 0, and 0 gets added to it, which gives 0, which will always be less than `l`, whatever that value is/means.

Since this is a school assignment, I hesitate to give you a straight-up answer. That's really not what SO is for, and I'm glad that you haven't solicited a full solution either.

So I'll direct you to some useful methods in Ruby instead that could help.

In Array: `.join`, `.each` or `.map`
In String: `.split`

Fyi, your TA's suggestion is far simpler than the algorithm you've decided to embark on... although technically, it is not wrong. Merely more complex.

Comment: So thus far I've corrected `i = i + i` to `i = i + 1` which results in the creation of the first file "Federalist No. 1"
But I'm still confused as to why the program fails to get to the else.

Comment: Oh, that's my fault. "l" is defined before the Federalist papers as `l = Array.new`
The array consists of all of the Federalist papers.

Comment: I'm curious if the array `l` merely comprises of one string element in it, with all the papers in that one fat string. In other words, how certain are you that `l.length` is actually greater than 1? Your TA's comment about implementing `.split` leads me to asking this question, because your code hasn't done a `.split` on the array of papers either.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, I'm fairly certain that l.length is greater than 1.

The array is formatted as such:
`l = Array.new


l[0]=" "


l[1]=" "


l[2]=" "


l[3]=" "


l[4]="FEDERALIST. No. 1"


l[5]=" "


l[6]="General Introduction"
...etc`

Comment: Also, my code didn't implement a `split` because I never turned the array into a string.

Comment: Based on the example of `l` you've just posted, your condition `if (l[i]!= "federalist") and (l[i+1]!= "No")` will always be satisfied, and you will never hit the `else` block. Take when i is 4. The first part of the condition will evaluate to true (`l[4]` is not 'federalist', but is actually 'FEDERALIST. No. 1'), and the second part of your condition will also evaluate to true (`l[4+1]`, which is `l[5]`, is a blank string, not "No".

Comment: With your TA's suggestions (i.e. using the methods I posted), the solution is literally just 3-5 lines long altogether.

Comment: Also... you aren't checking for case-sensitivity. 'Federalist' is not the same as 'FEDERALIST'.